# Как сделать роутинг файлов в nginx?

Tags: сервер, nginx, express

У меня есть папка `exemple.com` в которой находится nodejs сервер `app.js` и файл `file.js`. Ноду проксирует `nginx`, в котором нужно прописать путь до этого самого файла `file.js`. Как это сделать?
Ведь так можно?

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name exemple.com;

    root /home/ivan/server/exemple.com/public;
    index index.html;

    log_not_found off;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    location /file.js {
        root /home/ivan/server/exemple/file.js
    }
}
```

Comment: Хочу привлечь внимание администрацию ресурса к тому факту, что пользователи не знают о подписке на интересующие их теги. На sass около десяти человек подписаны, на express всего 82. Это ужастно отпугивает при выборе тегов при создании тем. Нет желания писать тег на который подписано пять человек. Это просто как орать в космос ..

Comment: внимание администрации лучше привлекать на [Мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно указать как минимум двумя вариантами.

директивой `root` указать каталог:

```
location /file.js { root /home/ivan/server/exemple/; }
```

либо директивой `alias` указать файл:

```
location /file.js { alias /home/ivan/server/exemple/file.js; }
```

понятно, что во втором случае имя файла может быть вовсе не `file.js`.

Comment: Спасибо! Первый, почему-то, не работае, хотя я даже с регуляркой пробовал по хелпу, но не помогло. А вот второй вариант работает.

Comment: и именно второго варианта я и добивался.